# why does dig udemy.com return 1.1.1.1?

Tags: dns, dig

So why does dig udemy.com return 1.1.1.1?

When I enter https://1.1.1.1 on the browser URL, it opens a landing page from Cloudflare.

````
; <<>> DiG 9.17.1 <<>> udemy.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18183
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;udemy.com.                     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
udemy.com.              58      IN      A       1.1.1.1

;; Query time: 28 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Jun 08 20:57:47 AUS Eastern Standard Time 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54```
````

Comment: In general, a server can run multiple services on one ip address (even multiple different websites).

Comment: 1) "So why does dig udemy.com return 1.1.1.1? " And why not? It is silly/useless, but every owner of a domain is free to put whatever it wants in its zonefile. Why is this fact suddenly a problem for you? what is the context? your problem regarding that?  and 2) your question is not related to programming so it is offtopic here.